# Get coordinates (latitude and longitude) from marker in Google Maps

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I started to use great package react-google-maps. Could you help me how can I get the values of latitude and longitude from inserted (clicked) marker?

If I log returned object I get scope which consist of latitude and longitude.. but I can not access to scopes..

[image]

I use something like this example https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/ with some changes. I want to store in states latitude and longitude from clicked marker.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you use `react-google-maps` and where do you want the coord? Please show us more details.

Comment: Hello @FiriceNguyen, I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want to get the list of longitude/latitude from the list of `Marker` within `state`.
Assuming `arr` is an array of `Marker` from google map:

`arr.map(x => x.position.lat())` will give you the latitude.

`arr.map(x => x.position.long())` will give you the longitude

Comment: Great! Your solution is what I was searching for. Thank you.